# Jquery get value from field onmouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try get value from input text field using jquery with the function `val()`

**Actually i use this :**

```
<input type="text" name="alias" value="Insert Value" id="register_input_text_form" onmouseleave="detect('this.val()')"/>
```

As you can see in the onmouseleave i try get the value that writte inside input text file , but no get the value , this val send to this function :

```
<script>
function detect(value)
{
alert(''+value);    
jQuery(".alias_loader").load("veritas.php?valend="+value);  
}
</script>
```

All works fine , only problem it´s get value from input text , i can´t use other class or id , because i need use the same name for others fields and the only solution it´s get the value finally from onmouseleave

Thank´s and regards to community for the help

Comment: You're passing the string, use jQuery instead of inline, `$('input').on('blur', function() { $(this).val(); });`

Comment: `detect(this.value)`

Comment: accept @PranavCBalan answer if it solves your issue, that will be useful for other users to find correct solution easily http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string parameter in event handler function not the input value. You need to change `detect('this.val()')` to `detect(this.value)`

```
<input type="text" name="alias" value="Insert Value" id="register_input_text_form" onmouseleave="detect(this.value)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

below should work

```
<input type="text" name="alias" value="Insert Value" id="register_input_text_form" onmouseleave="detect(this.val())"/>
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, the accepted answer includes an explanation of *why* this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @MaxLeske yes I understood that. Even I did +1 for accepted answer too.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing string to function so remove single quote replace like

```
onmouseleave="detect(this.value)"
```